# How to know allowed methods for one route in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, routes, http-method

I'm currently in a listener, and I want to return some headers in my response. `$this->router->match($this->request->getPathInfo());` I don't have any information about this. I have however specified the methods :

```
api_v2_spokespeople_collection:
  path: /spokespeople
  defaults: { _controller: "APIBundle:v2/Spokesperson:getCollection" }
  methods:  [GET, OPTIONS]
```

Is it finally possible without having to "manually" parse the routing files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a route name:

```
/** @var string $routeName */
/** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request */
$routeName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```

and you have the `@router` service (It seems this service was injected into your listener):

```
// from the controller action.
/** @var Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router $router */
$router = $this->get('router');

//in your sample should be $this->router directly.
```

then we can get the route instance and its information through route collection:

```
/** @var Symfony\Component\Routing\Route $route */
$route = $router->getRouteCollection()->get($routeName);
```

finally, you need to call to `getMethods()` to know the defined methods:

```
/** @var string[] $methods */
$methods = $route->getMethods(); // e.g. array('GET', 'POST')
```

---

In one line:

```
$methods = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($request->get('_route'))->getMethods();
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are going to get allowed methods for current route. If so then:

```
$route = $this->request->get('_route');
$methods = $route->getMethods();
```

Comment: I can't use this because when I dump `$route` i got `null`. It's really strange.

Comment: @fnev.eu make sure your listener is executed *after* the routing listener

Comment: @WouterJ yes, it's better ! But $route is now a string. when I try with router->match() method, I got an array without methods...

Comment: AFAIK `$request->get('_route')` returns a string always (by default) :/ ?https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L193